# How to detect invalid_client_id in oauth flow?

Tags: oauth2, error-messages

My web application follows the example in https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/tree/master/samples/WebServerOAuthFlow to initiate a traditional oauth flow. In my application, the user enters their client_id and secret and then initiates the oauth flow which opens a new browser window (window.open()) pointing to Salesforce to start the flow, the following url for example:

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=myreallylongclientid&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fsalesforce%2fcallback&display=page&immediate=False&state=5b6b5a10a221441695a3b5d729de05cf&scope=&prompt=page

What I found is if the client_id was mistyped, the user is given an less than helpful 
`error=invalid_client_id&error_description=client%20identifier%20invalid`. I can understand why it doesn't redirect to the redirect_uri since the client_id couldn't be validated. However, I was expecting a pretty Salesforce branded "There was a problem with your client id".  As it is, my window is dead and my initiating application has no idea there was a problem.

Am I missing a flag that would ask salesforce to give a pretty error message?

I don't think there's any way from the source web page to know that the window.open() resulted in a 400.

Comment: Is this a recurring problem? I've encountered this error message before, but once I get login flow configured correctly, it never pops up again. (At least not that I know of).

Comment: No, not recurring. Again, just happens when the user mistypes something. Usually they copy/paste, but it has happened.

Comment: Why do your users have to type that in anyways? What's stopping you from having your app build that url with the client id and automatically redirecting the users?

Comment: App does build the url, but the client_id bit is customer specific and each has their own salesforce instance. Usually they copy/paste and no problem. 
Every other oauth provider (Google, Dropbox, etc.) that I've used gives a prettier error message when something isn't quite right and cannot redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do a GET in javascript (ajax) to this?:

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=incorrectID&redirect_uri=http://www.somedomain.com

and see the response.

i.e., if text response from http then it's an error otherwise you are good to go so "really" login now.

Comment: Right, at least make sure it doesn't 400. It may redirect, but that's fine.